# Ui form: image field in Magento 2.2

Tags: php, magento2.2, image-upload, ui-form

I need to create a **image upload field** in my **Ui form**.

I have created below files.

But while trying to upload an image, it shows a below error.

Please suggest me a solution to save a image in DB.
I got following error
[image]

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\HomeSlider\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Namespace\Module\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('OX_HomeSlider::HomeSlider');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }

}
```

**di.xml**

```
<virtualType name="OXHomeSliderImageUploader" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">homeslider/tmp</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">homeslider</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\HomeSlider\Image\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">OXHomeSliderImageUploader</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

ox_homeslider_form.xml

```
<field name="image" formElement="fileUploader">
            <settings>
                <notice translate="true">Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.</notice>
                <label translate="true">Image</label>
                <componentType>fileUploader</componentType>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="string" name="url">ox_homeslider/homeslider_image/upload</param>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

**save.php**

```
namespace OX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $postModel = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post');

        if ($id) {
            $postModel = $postModel->load($id);
        }  
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        if(empty($post['id'])) {
             $post['id'] = null;
         }
        $postModel->setData($post);
        $postModel->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('homeslider/post/index');
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show up your controller used for save image in filesystem?

Comment: Can you show up your controller used for save image path in database?

Comment: No. I did'nt added anything additionally for image

Comment: There is an exit in your Upload.php, remove that

Comment: After uploading a image which is stored in pub/media folder. But it is not visible in grid and also Not saved in DB.. and that server error remains same. Am i need to change grid.xml for image to store image in DB

Comment: @Jayashree is it saving  the image in media/homeslider?

Comment: Yes . But it is saving the image as pub/media/saree.jpg

Comment: @Jayashree then this code is working perfect, the issue is in the controller which submits the form

Comment: Am i need to handle image in dataprovider.php

Comment: @Jayashree check in your save controller what data your getting in post and then try to debug the save action accordingly, you can ask another question to display image in grid. Also Please accept the below answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68745/discussion-between-jayashree-and-piyush).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is giving error because of this code

```
<uploaderConfig>
     <param xsi:type="string" name="url">theme/design_config_fileUploader/save</param>
</uploaderConfig>
```

Reason is the mentioned url `theme/design_config_fileUploader/save` may not exist or having wrong code.

you can refer category edit form and uploaded action for this, below are the path for files

**Category Form**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

**Upload Action**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php

Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180200/20064) to create controller action to upload image

### **Update:**

**change url in your above `<uploaderConfig>` node to below**

```
<uploaderConfig>
     <param xsi:type="string" name="url">namespace_module/module_image/upload</param>
</uploaderConfig>
```

**Create a controller action at path** Filename - `Upload.php`

> Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Module\Image

In this File add below code

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Module\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Namespace\Module\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Namespace_Module::Module');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

**Add below code to your module's  `etc/di.xml`**

```
<virtualType name="ModuleImageUploader" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader"><!-- replace Module with your entity name -->
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">module/tmp</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">module</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array"><!-- you can add here file extension restrictions -->
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Module\Image\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">ModuleImageUploader</argument><!-- again, replace Module with the name of your entity. Make sure it matches the name of the virtual type above. -->
    </arguments>
</type>
```

### Note: Do not forgot to change Namespace and Module to your Namespace and Module name

Comment: Am i need to create additional controller file for image upload?

Comment: yes you have to create  that controller to upload and save image at a particular directory. Check this answer
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180200/20064

Comment: Is this file can help for my custom form to upload an image Because it refers for catalog

Comment: this  file is to save your uploaded image in a particular directory which you have to mention in `di.xml` , image name will be save in database when you submit the form

Comment: I am unable to understand that code which is specified in core class. Can you explain me how to write controller for Upload.php

Comment: Please check above I have modified the answer as u said @Piyush